# Relaunch an app if it freezes

Tags: ubuntu, performance, freeze

Yesterday I successfully managed to make a kiosk from Ubuntu Server. I'm going to use it to rub some web application that will run non-stop.

However, in some cases, duo to lot of js animation I'm afraid that it may freeze/won't respond anymore and I won't be there to do anything.

Is there a way to run some commands once the browser freezes? Currently, when the OS launches it will trigger the kiosk in its own but if I want I can start and stop it manually with:

```
bash
sudo start kiosk
sudo stop kiosk
```

So I will need to run

```
bash
sudo stop kiosk
```

To close the current freezed browser instance (hopefully it will kill it since the server has no graphics but when I start the kiosk it's loading openbox and xset in order to see the browser, when I'm stopping the kiosk it stops those services as-well).

Then, I will need to run:

```
bash
sudo start kiosk
```

To relaunch everything.

So is it possible doing that once I somehow detect if the browser has frozen or not responding?

## Edit:

My kiosk files are as follows:

/opt/kiosk.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

xset -dpms
xset s off
openbox-session &

while true; do
  rm -rf ~/.{config,cache}/google-    chrome/
  google-chrome --kiosk --no-first-run  'http://thepcspy.com'
done
```

/etc/init/kiosk.conf:

```
start on (filesystem and stopped udevtrigger)
stop on runlevel [06]

console output
emits starting-x

respawn

exec sudo -u user startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sh --
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers freeze typically when they hog memory. Since you are running in kiosk mode you can find out the ideal memory usage by the browser , and also the memory it is taking when it actually gets hung while you are observing it.

Lets say it gets hung when you are working - just find out the memory it is taking by using

```
    ps -eo vsize,pid | grep <pid of the browser>
```

Now you know the limit that should not be crossed.

Just write a forever loop that keeps monitoring the vsize and if it exceeds just restart it. (this example keeps that limit at 12345)

```
    while true; do
        browser &
        p=$!
        echo "browser restarted with pid $p"
        while true; do
            sleep 1
            x=`ps -eo vsize,pid | grep $p | head -1 | awk '{print $1}' `
            echo "memory is $x"
            if [ "$x" -gt "12345" ]
              then
                kill -9  $p
                break
            fi
        done
    done
```

Comment: Thanks. When you say memory you mean RAM right? I have 4gb of ram on the machine. How would I find the browser pid? Where is it echoing everything? I will need some log file if possible. When you kill the browser, how would you re-open it? (My kiosk code will open the browser if the user closes it, will it work when killing the process as-well?) why do you back 2 infinite loops? Can you explain what they do in details for a newbie like me? `p.s. I run my browser with the command "Google-chrome --kiosk --no-first-run" and some other options. If you want I can add my kiosk file

Comment: Edited by post to reflect my kiosk setting. Would like to see how you combine these. Keep in my that I need some log file is possible.

Comment: the outer loop keeps running the browser infinitely, even if it has been killed.  
the inner loop keeps monitoring the vm size of the browser process- and kill it if necessary. As soon as the browser is killed, the inner loop is over and the outer loop restarts the browser.  
You can just replace "browser" in my example by "/opt/kiosk.sh" and it should work for you.  
Of course you have to get the right number to replace 12345, by doing a 

        ps -eo vsize,pid,cmd | grep google-chrome

to see the vsize at the time google-chrome is hung manually once, so that you can replace "12345"

Comment: Thanks! So basically I need to place your code in my `/etc/init/kiosk.conf`? Where would I put it? Also, if I run the `ps -eo` command once it will tell me at which memory usage the browser will freeze or I have to run it until a freeze happens? Maybe I can somehow write a script to monitor when the browser is freezed and when it does it will automatically set the an environment variable which your code can read? I'm kind of new to Linux so maybe you can help me take my idea into fruition

Comment: you will have to first find out the limit of freeze manually. This can only be done if you check after the browser freezes... it should be high enough

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, the "12345" is it in bytes or mega-bytes?

Comment: the vsize is in kbytes